# Notificaciones en 2do plano xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

como están?.

Les comento tengo una app de ejemplo (Estoy aprendiendo) en xamarin forms (Android e IOS).

Y en este momento estoy implementando notificaciones. Me resulto fácil haciéndolo cuando presiono un botón en la pantalla, pero ahora, quiero poder mostrarle notificaciones al usuario aunque la app este cerrada.

La idea es que cada x minutos se ejecute algún proceso en segundo plano, que verifique información y envíe una notificación al usuario.

¿Me podrían ayudar con esto?. Desde ya les agradezco la ayuda.

Que tengan buen día.

Comment: Este proceso en segundo plano, se ejecuta en el propio dispositivo o es algo externo?

Comment: Hola Leandro, como estás?. La idea es que cuando la app se encuentre cerrada, en segundo plano consulte una web api y si tiene información nueva le muestre una notificación al usuario para que pueda verla en la app. 
Espero me puedas ayudar y desde ya te lo agradezco.

Comment: El tema es que no deberia ser la app la que valide contra una webapi, sino que deberias usar servicio como ser SignalR o similar el que envie notificaciones al dispositivo, es el servidor el que notifica a la app mobile

Comment: Gracias Leandro. Supuse que tenia que ser asi. Solo que no quería meterme en ese tema. Pero tendré que hacerlo. Muchas gracias por tu guía. La pregunta aquí sería como gatillar el evento con signalr al cambiar la base de datos en un webhosting a la cuál no se le pueden instalar servicios.

Answer (score 1):

Lo correcto seria enviar notificaciones como `Push Server` del lado del servidor, lo mas simples si el server es una implementacion `.net web` seria hacerlo por medio de `SignalR`

[Real Time Communication for Mobile with SignalR (Core)](https://montemagno.com/real-time-communication-for-mobile-with-signalr/)

la idea es que crees un `Hub`

```
public class NotigicationHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

En el cliente `Xamarin` referencias usando nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client`, para recibir los mensajes

Pero si queria ir por un proceso en el dispositivo tienes la posibilidad de crear `Services` para realizar acciones en segundo plano

[Creating Android Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/)

[Xamarin Background Tasks](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/)

cambia segun la plataforma si es Android, iOS o UWP

Para crear el service necesitas que la clase herede de `Service`

```
[Service]
public class DemoService : Service
{
   // codigo
}
```

Puedes enviar notificaciones

[Service Notifications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/service-notifications)

usando el `Notification.Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Les agradezco vuestra ayuda. Puedo generar las notificaciones, pero siempre tengo que tener la aplicación abierta, aunque sea en segundo.
La idea es que aunque la aplicación este cerrada haya algún proceso que me permita cada intervalo de tiempo ejecute una acción y si es verdadera muestre una notificación.

Por ejemplo la mayoría utilizamos las apps de Facebook, Instragram y Whatsup, y estas aplicaciones aunque estén cerradas cuando existe un mensaje nuevo nos muestra una notificación. En realidad es lo que me gustaría lograr.

Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería mucho y gracias por lo que me han ayudado hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para generar notificaciones y funcionen en segundo plano, podes usar AppCenter de microsoft con las notificaciones push, entiendo que eso es lo que buscas lograr.
Cuando entras en App Center, tenes el instructivo de como llevarlo a cabo y es muy sencillo, también están los vídeos en los canales de youtube de Xamarin.
Este es el link exacto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TT11e_YCRwI para poder comenzar con notificaciones push, de ahí en adelante tenes mas funciones para agregar. 
Supongo que cuentas con un servicio web que enviara los mensajes.
Las opciones para hacer esto son: 
1-tener un servicio web que envíe los mensajes automáticamente.
2-Realizar una app web o móvil que de forma manual envíe notificaciones.
Una vez que hiciste las configuraciones principales que te dice el vídeo tenes que usar la api Rest que ellos te proveen para hacer lo que necesites, si es que queres mejorar las funcionalidades.

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.
Saludos

Comment: Hola Ramiro, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Pero por lo que entendí tu creas un centro de mensajes. Pero no aparece como dirigirlo a un usuario especifico. Por ejemplo, quiero recibir notificaciones de todos los mensajes nuevos que hay para mi y obviamente para otros usuarios les lleguen sus propias notificaciones. Y por último, centralizar esto en firebase y el app center no quita independencia de la app?. por ejemplo podría usar SignalR para crear un web api que rebice la base de datos y enviará los mensajes?. muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, el vídeo tiene una configuración general, luego puedes hacer el tipo de push que tu quieras, tal como lo hace whatsapp. Debes seguir los instructivos de las Api Rest. Y puedes crear el servicio en el lenguaje que tu quieras, luego llamas a la Api Rest de App Center y le pasas la informacion que sea necesaria segun tu necesidad, puede enviar mensajes a un grupo de usuarios, o a usuarios individiales.